# How to use 'children' jQuery selector to only show content of a child span of a div?

Tags: jquery

I have the html like this"

```
<div id="words" style="opacity: 1; visibility:hidden;">
    <div id="row1" style="top: 1px;">
        <span wordnr="0" class="highlight">took</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the **took** 
so how can i use the children jquery  for this ?

I have tried:

```
<script>
   var a=$("#words").children('#row1').children('.highlight');
   alert( a );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For valid html ids are unique so you can use only row1, One more thing put the code in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure availability to `javascript/jquery`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J2pLy/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#row1').children('.highlight').each(function(){
      alert($(this).text()); 
  });
});
```

You even do not need each if you get only one element by selector.

```
 var forTook = $('#row1').children('.highlight').text();
```

or

```
var forTook = $('#row1 .highlight').text();
```

Comment: if i have the html like this then what the code for out put took ?<div id="words" style="opacity: 1; visibility:hidden;">
    <div id="row1" style="top: 1px;">
        <span wordnr="0" class="highlight">took</span>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: html like this? One more thing put the code in document.ready to ensure availability

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate; you can't alert a jquery object like in your example:

```
var a = $("#words").children('#row1').children('.highlight');
```

In this case, `a` would be a jQuery object, which has an array-like structure.

With the above in mind (assuming that you have selected the right elements) you can iterate over it like in @Adil's example:

```
$.each(a, function(i, el){
    alert($(el).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use `.find()` with `.children()`

```
$("#words").children().find('.highlight').text();
```

Comment: if i have the html like this the wht should i use for output took ?<div id="words" style="opacity: 1; visibility:hidden;">
   <div id="row1" style="top: 1px;"><span wordnr="0" class="">took</span>

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `.highlight` elements in your HTML, you will have to iterate over them:

```
$('#row1 .highlight').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

This will return an array containing all of the highlighted words.

Comment: if i have the html like this the wht should i to get the word took ?<div id="words" style="opacity: 1; visibility:hidden;"> <div id="row1" style="top: 1px;"><span wordnr="0" class="">took</span>

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
<script>
   var a = $('#words').children('#row1').children('.highlight').text();
   alert( a );
</script>
```

As Adil has said, you'll need to loop over the matching elements if there are more than one.